# ASP.NET Web API complex parameters, omit variable or make a new one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

so I am having a little bit of trouble wording this question, but hopefully my code will show what I am trying to do.

So I have a POST method that allows the consumer to add a new Company.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public object PostCompany([FromBody] Company companyModel, int userId)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = _companyRepository.PostCompany(companyModel, userId);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "An error has occured");
        }
    }
```

The issue is that companyModel contains a CompanyId, but that should not be provided as it will be auto generated on the DB side.  Is there a way to not require part of the Company object or would I need to rewrite the parameters for this endpoint to only contain the parts of the Company object that I want to accept for this endpoint?  Or even more, should I just create a new model to be used for POSTing a company?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Read about proper layering, single responsibility, DTOs and so on. Consensus: don't use Entity Framework models as models in your API or MVC application. Use DTOs.

Comment: Ok, I read up a little bit about DTOs and the examples that I saw seem to take a Company object and map it to a CompanyDTO because what the consumer wants to see is not a Company object, but a more customized CompanyDTO.

If that is accurate, would I just do it in reverse in my case?  [FromBody] CompanyDTO companyModel, and just map it to the Company object as needed?

Comment: That's right. :) Your Entity Model contains properties you don't want the consumer to see, and a model that your consumer posts to your API may contain properties you don't want in your database. So introduce a DTO and map from and to that.